# Наполнение Sqlite таблицы данными через массив строк

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Здравствуйте. Проблема в том что у меня не получается наполнить таблицу из ресурсов (в strings.xml у меня лежит массив данных)

```
    <item>Barsik</item>
    <item>Myrka</item>
    <item>Vasiliy</item>



</string-array>
```

Теперь я не могу его вытянуть в базу данных, у меня выводит только последний элемент (в данном случае "Vasisiliy"). 
Вот мои класы:
DataBaseHelper - тут просто создаем бд

```
package database.test.zapovnenna_tablici_sql;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 13.04.2015.
 */
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cat_database.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "cattable";
  public Context fContext;



    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context ,DATABASE_NAME, null , 1);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + "title TEXT" + ");");



    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w("TestBase", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

И собственно MainActivity

```
package database.test.zapovnenna_tablici_sql;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sql = db.getWritableDatabase();


        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        Resources res = db.fContext.getResources();
        String[] cattable_records = res.getStringArray(R.array.catList);

        for (int i = 0; i < cattable_records.length; i++) {
            cv.put("title", cattable_records[i]);
            sql.insert(db.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);


        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        for (int i = 0; i < cattable_records.length; i++) {
            tv.setText(cattable_records[i]);
        }
        sql.close();
        db.close();
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема вывода? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < cattable_records.length; i++) {
            tv.setText(cattable_records[i]);
        }
```

Само собой - выводится только последний элемент. Проведем параллели:
tv - стул. cattable_records - массив из котов. Вы в цикле для каждого элемента массива говорите: "кот из массива под номером *i*, сгони того, кто там сейчас сидит, и сядь на стул!"
Сначала туда садится Barsik, потом встает Barsik и садится Myrka, затем встает Myrka и садится Vasiliy. Кто в итоге там останется?
Что бы вывелись все элементы:

```
String cats  = "";
for (int i = 0; i < cattable_records.length; i++) {
    cats = cats + cattable_records[i] + ";";
}
tv.setText(cats);
```

В итоге получится

> Barsik;Myrka;Vasiliy;